# PDO wordpress query

Tags: php, database, wordpress, pdo

I keep getting

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Please help! =] 
I've checked that this literal query in phpmyadmin works.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `wp_customgravityall` 
WHERE  (`time` >= '2015-09-01 00:00:00' AND `time` <= '2015-09-13 23:59:59')
ORDER BY  `wp_customgravityall`.`time` DESC
```

But my code below doesn't work.

```
<?php
$servername = "http://www.myhomepagenamethingy.com/";
$username = DB_USER;
$password = DB_PASSWORD;
$dbname = DB_NAME;

$table_name = 'wp_' . 'customgravityall';

$from_date  = isset( $_GET['from_date'] )   ? $_GET['from_date'] . " " . "00:00:00" : '';
$to_date    = isset( $_GET['to_date'] )     ? $_GET['from_date'] . " " . "23:59:59" : '';


try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:$servername;dbname=$dbname', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $statement = $conn->prepare(
        "SELECT * 
        FROM ? 
        WHERE `time` >= ? AND `time` <= ?
        ORDER BY `wp_customgravityall`.`time` DESC"
    );
    $statement->bindValue(1, $conn->quote($table_name), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindValue(2, $conn->quote($from_date), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindValue(3, $conn->quote($to_date), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    var_dump($statement);
    $statement->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'PDO ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to bind a table with `FROM ?`

The rule in prepared statements is you **cannot** bind tables/columns.

You either select a table name, assign a variable to a table name, or use a safelist.

Example of setting a table name to a variable:

```
$table = "table_name";
```

then

```
SELECT FROM $table
```

or with ticks around the table name, should your table contain a character that MySQL will complain about, such as a space or hyphen:

```
SELECT FROM `$table`
```

In your case, the variable to use is `$table_name`

- You will then need to readjust your binds accordingly.

Another thing I spotted is that you are using single quotes here:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:$servername;dbname=$dbname', $username, $password);
```

Variables do not get parsed in single quotes (unless concatenated), use double quotes:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

However, your construct seems off, so you "might" have to adjust it.

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Example from the manual:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", $user, $pass);
```

However, I may be wrong about this since I do believe there are a few methods to construct a connection with PDO.

Therefore change it to:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
```

Plus, make sure those [**constants**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) have been correctly assigned.

These are considered as constants and not strings:

```
$username = DB_USER;
$password = DB_PASSWORD;
$dbname = DB_NAME;
```

If those are not predefined constants, you need to wrap those in quotes:

```
$username = "DB_USER";
$password = "DB_PASSWORD";
$dbname = "DB_NAME";
```

Then this:

```
$servername = "http://www.myhomepagenamethingy.com/";
```

That should more than likely be `localhost` set in quotes, or an IP address depending on how your system is setup, and is the usual setting and not a URL. If that doesn't work out for you with what I already gave you in my answer, you will need to find out what your host setting is.

Comment: thanks for spotting the quotations as well. This definitely solved the syntax error. I am getting a no database selected error, even though I've confirmed my database name. Is due to an incorrect  database host name?

Comment: @ahnbizcad you're welcome. I made a few edits to my answer after spotting your connection method. Reload it to see them under where it says *"However, your construct seems off, so you "might" have to adjust it....."* - it's the missing "host=". See the manual about it also. Also check your constants.

Comment: @ahnbizcad I made a few more edits. After spotting what you have for `$servername`. Do reload it again and go through it in its entirety.

Comment: ah, even after reading it, the `host=` portion was completely bypassing my visual and mental radar. It's always the things you think aren't the problem :p  Now I just need to grant permissions to the username i specified. =]

Comment: @ahnbizcad Yeah, those little things can escape us all every once in a while. *Cheers*

Comment: I really don't get that downvote. Shee-it, some poor bastard just loves living a miserable life. And that poor bastard's name has no f'ing sense.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I got your back, you got the most detailed answers ever!

Comment: Thanks @meda *ditto bro* ;-) Cheers

Answer (score -1):

***MY SOLUTION FOUND:***

The solution found was to change the username and password in the file that connects the cms with the database and I saw that suddenly it could be the username that has a dot or is the same domain name.

***PROCESS STEPS OF to UP TO FIND CONCLUSION***

In Wordpress I was having a problem between mysqli and PDO.
I solved it with the command yum update & yum upgrade, no centos and he gave me the following updates:

```
================================================== 
   ==============================
 Package Arch Version Repository Size
 ==================================================                             
==============================     
Installing:
 lsphp73-mysqlnd x86_64 7.3.15-1.el7 litespeed 132k
```

replacing lsphp73-mysqlnd.x86_64 7.3.14-1.el7
           Updating:
        lsphp73 x86_64 7.3.15-1.el7 litespeed 5.0 M
      lsphp73-bcmath x86_64 7.3.15-1.el7 litespeed 27 k
    lsphp73-common x86_64 7.3.15-1.el7 litespeed 650 k
     lsphp73-gd x86_64 7.3.15-1.el7 litespeed 114 k
     lsphp73-imap x86_64 7.3.15-1.el7 litespeed 32k
     lsphp73-mbstring x86_64 7.3.15-1.el7 litespeed 559 k
     lsphp73-opcache x86_64 7.3.15-1.el7 litespeed 191 k
     lsphp73-pdo x86_64 7.3.15-1.el7 litespeed 67 k
     lsphp73-process x86_64 7.3.15-1.el7 litespeed 29 k
     lsphp73-soap x86_64 7.3.15-1.el7 litespeed 120 k
     lsphp73-xml x86_64 7.3.15-1.el7 litespeed 126 k
     openlitespeed x86_64 1.6.9-1.el7 litespeed 37 M

Transaction Summary
================================================== ==============================
Install 1 Package
Upgrade 12 Packages

Total download size: 44 M
Downloading packages:
No Presto metadata available for litespeed

---

Total 13 MB / s | 44 MB 00:03

Besides that mine
     fastcgi_pass unix: /var/php-nginx/15822663384347.sock/socket;

It was causing conflict.

but it still didn't solve the problem.